# Does Flink keyby on the same field which isn't changed cause a shuffle?

Tags: apache-flink, shuffle

```
dataStream.map(func1).keyBy("key") //(1)
  .process(func2).keyBy("key")     //(2)
  .timeWindow().aggregate(func3).addSink(sink)
```

Method process() doesn't change the field(key) value of records. Given that the parallelism of all operators is 2, does keyBy() at (2) also result in network shuffle? Maybe keyBy() at (2) has the effect of forward strategy avoiding network communication cost due to the unchanged key value?

Thx soooo much~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A keyBy is always expensive, because it forces the records to go through ser/de. But in the case where the communication is local -- i.e., within the same task slot -- then Flink will use a shared buffer to communicate the serialized bytes, rather than going through the whole netty tcp stack. So yes, in your case the second keyBy is less expensive than the first one. But I would not say the cost is small.

If you know that the keyBy is completely unnecessary, you can use [reinterpretAsKeyedStream](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/experimental.html) to get back to having a `KeyedStream` again without any of this overhead.

Comment: Thx, David! Though the second keyBy() results in network shuffle, the shuffle cost is still small because for each partition the keyBy() output isn't tranferred to other partition(unlike the first keyBy()), right?

Comment: No, the cost is still quite high, since it will serialize/deserialize all of the records.

Comment: Thx. I mean the cost of the second keyBy is lower than the first keyBy. For the 2nd keyBy(), timeWindows() requests result (sub)partition by LocalInputChannel if timeWindows() task is deployed on the same TaskManager(even the same slot) as process() task(Flink can optimize the deployment like this). Under this circumstance, only serialization and deserialization penalty hits. However there is no network io cost compared to the first keyBy(), right? @David Anderson

Comment: @DavidAnderson, is there a way of sorting the group of data with the same key, based on custom data attribute (after keyBy) ? I am facing the following issue: 2 parallel filters receive data in chronological order, then do key-by into 1 function (the key is, say, "countryname") but in the function, the records for same key occur in random order (not chronological)

Comment: Sorting by timestamp is easy with Flink SQL, but is otherwise a nuisance.